# Jquery ui Tabs Dialog PreventDefault

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, dialog, anchor

I'm new to jquery and I'm trying to bind a dialog to a tab in jquery ui, the tab has an anchor which will be used in dialog to create data from the form in the dialog. Tabs and dialog works fine but I can't seem to make e.preventDefault to work correctly. It always jumps and tries to load anchor content in tab content.

The goal of the dialog is to add a new tab, something similar with what you can see here
http://freewebmentor.com/demo/addtabs.html

This is what I've got

```
$(function() {
    $("a#add").on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $('<form class="dialog-form">'+'<p><label>'+'Name'+'</label><span><input class="input-text" type="text" name="name" /></span></p>'+'</form>');

        $form.dialog({
            width:     235,
            modal:     true,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            title:     'Create'
        });
    });

    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

and

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($data as $item): ?>
    <li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $item->id;?>"><?php echo $item->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <li><a id="add" href="<?php echo link('cp/create/item/'.$item->id); ?>" title="Add Item">+</a></li>
</ul>

<?php foreach($data as $item): ?>
<div id="tabs-<?php echo $item->id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item[<?php echo $item->id; ?>][name]" value="<?php echo $item->name; ?>" />
    <textarea name="item[<?php echo $item->id; ?>][content]"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($item->content); ?></textarea>
 </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I've searched a lot but none of the solutions works for me.

**Edit:**

Manage to do it with this

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeLoad: function (e, ui) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Any one with a better idea?

Comment: If you have full control of the markup (as your second code snippet seems to suggest) why bother with an `<a>` tag at all? You're already using jQ to create a custom click handler, so make your element with ID of `add` something like a `<span>` and you won't even have to worry about preventing the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/EbQ2x/)**

I have added a link like:

```
<a href="sdfds" id="add_tab_link">Add Tab (this is a link)</a>
```

and js code for opening the modal on click of link is:

```
$( "#add_tab_link" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert('clicked');
        dialog.dialog( "open" );
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to find an small solution for my problem with this bit of code.
If anyone else as a better idea I would love to know about it.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    beforeLoad: function (e, ui) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```